# Is it possible to share HttpSession via redis between services that use different versions of Spring Security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-session

I am working on a product that's implemented using the micro-services architecture. Each microservice is deployed as a SpringBoot application.
Some of these microservices have SpringSecurity and they use Redis to share the session between each other so that users don't have to log in again when making requests to different services.
The problem I am facing now is related to migrating those apps from SpringBoot 2 to SpringBoot 3. When one of the services is running on SpringBoot 3 and saves the session on redis,
then the other services running on SpringBoot 2 cannot deserialize the object that was saved on redis, becuase the `serialVersionUID` doesn't match.

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.DefaultOAuth2User; 
local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 600, local class serialVersionUID = 580
```

The only solution I can think of is migrating and deploying all these services at the same time, but that's not very practical in my scenario.
I would love to be able to migrate them one by one while the product still works seamlessly.

Is there a way around this problem?

I am investigating how SpringSession gets saved on redis, and see if I can customize what gets saved - there maybe I could provide my own class that gets saved and then use it across all the services. But, I didn't manage to make any headway in that direction.

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks!